# Splitting the string by space?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string like `timestamp 32.828000?`
I want to extract only `32.828000` from above string and store in adjacent cell.

I do
`=left(b1,len(b1)-1)`
i get `timestamp 32.828000`
Now how do I split the above string and get the second element `32.828000` after split? I am new to Excel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of hints:
- if you have always "timestamp " at the beginning of the string and length of number is variable: `=right(b1,len(b1)-10)`
- if you know only that there is a space (it'll split at the first one!!): `=right(b1,len(b1)-find(" ",b1))`
- if you don't insist on formula than "text to columns" function of Excel is also nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=RIGHT( B1, LEN( B1 ) - FIND( " ", B1 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND` to get the position of the space in the string (add one to get the position of the character just after it), then grab everything after it, and assuming you have the result of the first formula in C1, then you can use:

```
=MID(C1, FIND(" ",C1)+1, 1000)
```

I used 1000 to grab everything after the space, but it's an arbitrary value.

Or if you want to use a single formula, you could do something like:

```
=MID(B1, FIND(" ",B1)+1, LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of the cells will always have `timestamp` preceding the value a straightforward substitution is conceptionally easier to follow.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"timestamp ", "")
```

Assuming your original string is in cell `A1`. Note the trailing space after `timestamp`.

This essentially takes the value in cell A1, and replaces instances of `timestamp` with `""`. Yes the empty speech marks indicate nothing hence removes it.

If case is a problem use `UPPER` to get a consistent input for substitution.